# Crear una imagen de Moodle en mi Localhost

Tags: moodle

estoy haciendo unas prácticas de Empresa y es la primera vez que trabajo con moodle, así que perdón si no formulo bien la pregunta.
Se trabaja con una versión 2.0 y veo que hasta poder actualizar a la 3.5 necesito ir actualizando progresivamente pues no se puede hacer de una sóla vez.
No me gustaría perder información y ya me he hecho una copia de las carpetas de mi servidor pero me gustaría **saber si puedo instalar una copia/imagen de mi moodle en mi local host, de forma que pueda trabajar las actualizaciones primero en Local y luego en el servidor.**  Espero haber sabido expresarlo.
gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Si por supuesto tienes que recolectar los siguientes datos.

- Los archivos de moodle que tengas actualmente
- Los archivos de Moodledata. La ruta de este lo podes ver en el archivo config.php de moodle bajo la variable $CFG->dataroot.
- Dump de la base de datos Guardado en un archivo sql.
- Opcional: modificar todos los strings del dump de la base de datos, reemplazando todas las apariciones de tu dominio actual por el dominio local que vas a usar.

Una vez que tienes todo esto sigue estos pasos

- Colocar el directorio de moodle en el webserver de tu maquina local. Por ejemplo si te instalaste un lamp y tienes el document root por defecto, coloca todos los archivos en /var/www/html.
- Colocar el directorio moodledata en una ruta con permisos de lectura y escritura
- Restaurar la base de datos del dump en alguna base de datos local
- Modificar el archivo config.php con los datos de tu instalación local. Deberías actualizar la ruta $CFG->dataroot y modificar los datos de conexión a la base de datos.
- Ingresar al dominio local que tengas configurado como webserver

Comment: Gracias Daniel, Al final lo solventé de una forma muy similar solo que en lugar de instalarlo en local me lo llevé a otro servidor en que hago pruebas. Pero tu respuesta es muy estructurada y correcta. De nuevo gracias.